# Test JSON-returning controller method without MissingViewError

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I am testing a Controller method that has only a JSON view. My method runs as expected, but the test method only returns "MissingViewException". Is there a solution to avoiding this exception in the unit test (besides inserting an empty file at View/People/map_leads.ctp)?

PeopleController.php

```
public function mapLeads($territory_id = null) {
    $leads = $this->Person->getPeople([
        'territory_id' => $territory_id
    ]);
    $this->set('leads', $leads);
}
```

AppController.php

```
public $components = ['RequestHandler'];
```

routes.php

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

PeopleControllerTest.php

```
public function testMapLeads() {
    $id = 40;
    $result = $this->testAction('/people/mapLeads/' . $id, array('return' => 'vars'));
}
```

View/People/json/map_leads.ctp exists and is properly utilized by CakePHP; it is only the test that wants to see View/People/map_leads.ctp.

I checked at [CakePHP: calling testAction to a json-returning method causes missing view exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459768/) reminding about adding RequestHandler to $components. This does not resolve the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't issuing a JSON request/accessing a JSON endpoint, as neither your request URL does contain the `.json` extension, nor does your request send an appropriate `Accept` header (I don't remember whether the latter is possible with the 2.x controller test case class at all).

Use the `.json` extension and you should be good.

```
$this->testAction('/people/mapLeads/' . $id . '.json', array('return' => 'vars'));
```

Answer (score -2):

Write this code inside your action.

`$this->autoLayout = false;
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type('application/javascript');`